# Как удалить все спрайты добавленные ранее в spriteKit

Tags: swift, spritekit, спрайт

Добрый день не могу понять как удалить `node` или спрайт с полигона, точнее несколько спрайтов все спрайты статичны и не как не контактирую ни между собой.

по всему инету искал, но не нашел

примеры типа `self.removeFromParent()` не помогают

у меня есть

```
        var spriteNames = ["asterisk","Circle-icon","minus","ok","plus","star","triangle","x"]
    // Установка элементов по горизонтали
                for i in 1...numberOfElements {

                    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: defaultFrontSprite)

                    let calc1:Float = Float(i) - 0.5
                    let calc2:Float = Float(i) - 0.5

                    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(calc1 * Float(sprite.frame.size.width) + calc2 * padding + offset), yOffset)
                    nodesPoints += [(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y)]

                    sprite.xScale = 0.5
                    sprite.yScale = 0.5

                    nodes.append(false)

                    sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
                    sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
                    sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
                    sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
                    sprite.name = defaultFrontSprite + String(element)
                    //sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = spriteCategory

                    element += 1
                    self.addChild(sprite)
                }
// какой то код...
```

как удалить например все `node` и спрайты с полигона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удалить все

```
self.removeAllChildren()
```

либо удалить конкретного через

```
self.removeChildrenInArray([spriteToDelete])
```

либо вы можете получить список всех детей через `self.children` и потом удалить какие вам надо. например так

```
for child in self.children {
    child.removeFromParent()
}
```

Все это есть в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/) по `SKNode`

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, но я не могу толком понять как пользоваться документацией, точней например я понял там указанны классы, а вот как понять, что делают какие свойства. я просто привык к php.net документации, там просто все и понятно, а тут как то все странно, но все же спасибо думаю со временем разберузь

Comment: там на все написано, что оно принимает, что оно возвращает и как им пользоваться. по моему довольно детально

Comment: ok, спасибо как начал сам ковыряться в xcode начал немного догонять что к чему